ArgoCD prune issue with the kiali-viewer role when installing Kiali
ArgoCd is showing the kiali-viewer role as pruned when trying to install Kiali-operator following the official docs via the ArgoCD.
The role is suppose to be added to each namespace. The role does exist in the cluster.
I tried uninstalling and then installing again.
The kiali-viewer role is suppose to be added to each namespace.

Has anyone had success in installing Kiali using ArgoCD?
